# getting log for hybrid app(ionic) on android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, console, ionic-framework

I am having an unexpected result with my hybrid app(ionic framework) and the problem only replicates it self when i deploy the apk on an android phone. It works perfectly in a browser.

Is there a way i can see the logs when it is running on the phone? so i can try to understand what the problem is and where its coming from.

I have tried to run the app on my phone using `ionic run android -l -c`. But when i do that the app works perfectly like it does on the browser. i realised it basically just plugs itself to my local server and serves it on my phone from there (i alerted the index url. as an app it shows `android_assets/www/index.html` but when running with the above commant it shows `http://192.168.XX.XXX/#/index`)

How can i see logs when installed as an apk? Please Help

PS: im a newbie at ionic/AngularJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a life saver for you and many others.

1. Install the app on the device.
2. Make sure you have `USB debugging` on on the real device.
3. On your desktop open Chrome, and in the URL address bar type
   `chrome://inspect`

Here you'll be able to see the list of devices that are connected and are using `WebView`. Click on inspect and you will be able to use Chrome Dev Tools on your running APK.

Comment: You are a life saver....Thank you @karran Been battling this for days. It worked. was able to find the error. apparently android webview has a different file system than on web so i had to appent urls with `/android_assets/www/XXXX`